# fetching only the most recent row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i tried simple

```
select date_created from smc_log_messages where rownum =1
order by date_created desc
```

and it returns a date like

```
15-SEP-16 10.15.49.099000000 PM
```

However, when i run

```
 select date_created from smc_log_messages 
    order by date_created desc
```

I see data like

```
30-SEP-16 12.39.00.006000000 AM
30-SEP-16 12.38.59.997000000 AM
```

So, basically adding the rownum is affecting the results. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you can just order it by desc

Answer (score 10):

If you want the most recent date, then use:

```
select max(date_created)
from smc_log_messages ;
```

If you want the most recent row in Oracle 12C+:

```
select lm.*
from smc_log_messages lm
order by lm.date_created desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions:

```
select lm.*
from (select lm.*
      from smc_log_messages lm
      order by lm.date_created desc
     ) lm
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the MAX function only to get the latest and top record:
SELECT MAX()
FROM

this will work.